# Return a range object using an IF statement in VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, range

I'm a beginner with VBA and am looking for help with my question. I am trying to do the following:

1. Loop through a column in my spreadsheet to find the row corresponding to two a combination of two values
2. Then loop through the row corresponding to that combination going horizontally to return the range of all values that pass an if-statement (>40) (the set of numbers that pass the if statement are always sequential & only one set per row i.e. (15, 34, 32, 42, 45, 56, 67, 56, 43, 39, 23, 14)
3. I would like to be able to also return the column number of the first and last value that pass the if statement to be able to extract a date range in another row

In pseudo code it would be something like this:

```
For r = 1 To 10000 'Loop through 10000 rows to find the correct ACV field
                If WkSht.Range("B" & r).Value = "%ACV" And WkSht.Range("C" & r) = bp_upc Then
                    'For column in row(r)
                        'If column > 40 add cell address to range object to be returned
                    'Next Column
                'End If
```

Then use the column component of the first and last cell address in that range to get the values in another row.

Any help or tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
public sub test
  dim res as range
  dim i as long

  for i = 1 to 10000
    if WkSht.cells(i, 2).value = "%ACV" and WkSht.cells(i, 3) = bp_upc then
      dim numbers_range as range
      with application.intersect(WkSht.rows(i), WkSht.usedrange)
        set numbers_range = WkSht.range(WkSht.cells(i, 4), .cells(.cells.count))
      end with

      if res is nothing then
        set res = Get40Range(numbers_range)
      else
        dim current_res as range
        set current_res = Get40Range(numbers_range)

        if not current_res is nothing then set res = application.union(res, current_res)
      end if
    end if
  next

  'use res
  'e.g. print res.address, do res.select or loop over res.areas
end sub

private function Get40Range(byval row as range) as range
  dim c as range, start40 as range, end40 as range

  for each c in row
    if c.value > 40 then
      if start40 is nothing then set start40 = c
      set end40 = c
    elseif c.value <= 40 and not start40 is nothing then
      exit for
    end if
  next

  if end40 is nothing and not start40 is nothing then
    set end40 = row.cells(row.cells.count)
  end if

  if not start40 is nothing then set Get40Range = start40.resize(, end40.column - start40.column + 1)
end function
```

Comment: Wowza - that's a lotta work for the little pseudo code supplied. Hope it's appreciated!

Comment: @GSerg Thank you for the quick reply. The code you provided does exactly what I need so it was extremely helpful. I had to look up several functions you used but it's starting to make sense. Thanks again!